# How to change default account for "From" in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I managed to set my 2nd mail account as my new default mail account. So in Thunderbird, the previously 2nd account folder shows up on top now.

But when *sending* an email, the default "From" address is still picked from the previous default mail account (default identity from account), and not from the new default mail account.

I restarted Thunderbird, but the issue remains.

Do I need to change the default account for the "From" as well? If so, how can I do that? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting Windows, the problem was solved, and the default from address was chosen correctly from my new default mail account.

Answer (score 0):

Thhunderbird's account settings include:

[image: Thunderbird Account Settings]

If you set the **Email Address** and **Reply-to Address** fields correctly, these should appear as the **From** and **Reply to** in your sent e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

*There isn't* something as a *general* "default From: address".

In each moment you have one of your accounts *selected* - e. g. by clicking to one of it sub-folders.

The "Default From: address" will be the *actually selected account* e-mail address.