# Thunderbird: How to use the same identity for multiple mail accounts

Tags: thunderbird

As noted in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1332684/176100), Thunderbird (with multiple mail accounts) always selects the default identity of the *currently selected* account when opening a "Write" window for a new email.

For one of my accounts, I want to default to an identity from a *different* account.
Is there a way to set another account's identity as the default — without manually recreating it wherever I want to use it?

Comment: All you need to do is to click in the *From* account-name box and select a different account. Why make this change permanent??

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird stores identities independently from accounts and only maintains a list of relations between them.
By manually editing your settings file, you can link the *same* identity to multiple accounts; even subsequent changes to the identity will be reflected on all accounts.

1. Exit Thunderbird.
2. Open your [`prefs.js` configuration file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) (found in your Thunderbird profile directory) in a text editor.
3. Search for the account configuration opens — named `mail.account.account1.server`, `mail.account.account1.identities`, etc.
   You may want to look at the server (`mail.server.server1.*`, etc) and identity (`mail.identity.id1.*`) definitions to find the account and identity you want to link.
4. Edit `mail.account.accountX.identities` to add the identities you want to use on that account. The first identity in the list will be used as the default for that account.
   The result may look something like this:

   ```
   user_pref("mail.account.account1.identities", "id4,id1,id2");
   user_pref("mail.account.account1.server", "server1");
   user_pref("mail.account.account4.identities", "id4,id3,id1,id2");
   user_pref("mail.account.account4.server", "server4");
   ```
5. The identities "id4", "id1", and "id2" will now show up on both "account1" and "account4".